# Change colour of a cell based on the value in the cell and text in another cell

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, excel-formula

I am after some help with either conditional formatting or VBA code.

I need to change the colour of a cells in column B of a spreadsheet where the following rules are met -

- The adjacent cell in column A contains either the text "F1" or
  "F2"
- The value of the cell in column B is greater than 7

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, and what didn't work. Also describe anything related you've found out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following columns

```
COLUMN A    COLUMN B
F1          2
F2          3
F1          4
F2          5
F1          7
F2          9
```

1. Step 1 - Select the column where you want to apply the formatting
2. Step 2 - Go to `Home Tab -->Conditional formatting-->New Rule`
3. Step 3 - On the popup window (`New Formatting rule`), click on Use a
   `formula to determine which cells to format` and on the `Edit the
   rule Description` enter the following formula
   `=(AND(OR(A2="F1",A2="F2"),B2>7))`
4. Step 4 - Click on `Format` and apply the necessary formatting (font,
   background color)

Here is the image in case you get lost

[image]

Comment: Except it as answered (click the grey tic-mark on the left hand side of your question)